# Selecting a single column doesn't seem to reduce the amount of data scanned in AWS Athena

Tags: parquet, amazon-athena

I'm experimenting with Athena queries of data stored in parquet in s3.
I've added a partition on the column `daystamp`, and as expected, when I create a query that uses it, it reduces the amount of data scanned.

However, when I limit the columns to return in the `SELECT` statement, I would expect it to reduce the amount of scanned data again, but it doesn't, it only speeds up the query.

Am I wrong to think it reduces the amount of data scanned?

Examples below: (the runtime decreases from 11s to 5s, but the Data scanned remains 2.08MB)

#### SELECT *

[image]

---

#### SELECT "column"

[image]

---

#### SELECT "column.field"

[image]

### Edit:

Added `SHOW CREATE TABLE logdata`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `logdata`(
  `cells` struct<voltages:array<double>,temperatures:array<int>,capacities:array<double>,soc:array<double>,duty:array<int>,resistance:array<double>> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `pack` struct<outputvoltage:string,packvoltage:string,current:string> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `timestamp` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `daystamp` string, 
  `deviceid` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'paths'='cells,daystamp,deviceId,pack,timestamp') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucketname/v1/logdata/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='ndjsonToParquet', 
  'averageRecordSize'='378', 
  'classification'='json', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'objectCount'='162', 
  'recordCount'='232193', 
  'sizeKey'='88003003', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Comment: In my opinion you should perform this test with bigger amount of the data, then you should see the differences.

Comment: The thought crossed my mind, but the cell column is one of 10 columns so while It may have some overhead, I don't see why I wouldn't get *some* reduction.
Otherwise, I'm wondering if the data scanned field in the UI only shows reductions from partitions and not selections

Comment: I did some tests and it works. Could you send the definition of your table?     SHOW CREATE TABLE logdata;

Comment: Thanks @j.b.gorski. I've updated the question with the response

Comment: From that, it looks like the queries are actually on json files, not parquet. I think I must have something wrong in the firehose/glue set up. Do you agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed. You don't use parquet format in your table. The right table should use the SerDe like this:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe
```

You need to transform this data first, you can also transform struct and array types. You can do this by using AWS GLUE or CTAS command in Athena.